# GDB M/I disable hardware watchpoints

Tags: gdb

Is there a way to disable hardware watchpoints in GDB/MI?

It's possible using the console interface with the following command:

```
set can-use-hw-watchpoints 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anything that can be done from the CLI can also be done via MI.

One simple, generic way is to just send the CLI command.  MI will understand this.  So, your MI client can just send `set can-use-hw-watchpoints 0`.

However, for the specific case of `set`, you can use the MI `-gdb-set` command.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. How to use -gdb-set to set that specific option? I tried a few ways but they didn't work.

Comment: nevermind, I misspelled `can-use-hw-watchpoints`, so the correct command is `-gdb-set can-use-hw-watchpoints 0`